# Using variables in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning javascript and i use jquery framework for some learning...
please can someone explain to me how to use this sample to alert byebye instead of hello

better question will be how to change var msg in function change

```
var msg = 'hello';
function change() {
msg = 'byebye';
}
alert(msg);​
```

Comment: Call `change();` before `alert(msg);` :) Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MUvdp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if `change()` was invoked before the `alert()`, it would do what you expect.

Try this for instance:

```
var msg = 'hello';

function change() {
  msg = 'byebye';
}

change();
alert(msg);​
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var msg = 'hello';

function change() {
    msg = 'byebye';
    return msg;
}

alert(change());​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var msg = 'hello';
function change() {
msg = 'byebye';
}
change();
alert(msg);​
```

You should call the change function first.

Answer (score 0):

Here `msg` is in scope of window object ..

Also you have not called the `change()` function

So it correctly prints `"hello"`

Call the function before alert and you will see what you expected..

```
change();
alert(msg);​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/NTSAq/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have done this right, in a sense. What you first set up was a global variable

```
var msg = 'hello';
```

you then defined a function with scope to that variable

```
function change(){
 msg = 'byebye';
}
```

and then you tested:

```
alert(msg);
```

However, what you never did was call your function. When you define a function you need to call it for its code to run, like this:

```
change();
alert(msg);
```

---

**Some function tips**

*Use a closure*

If you want to look at best practices for this situation, I would suggest not using the global namespace. You can do that with what is called a closure. It basically wraps the local scope of a function around your code. Child functions inside of this scope share scope.

```
(function(){
 var msg = 'hello';
 function change(){
  msg = 'byebye';
 }
 change();
 alert(msg);
})();//Wrapping the function in () and then using () on it will cause it to run the code without being called
```

Not only will this leave the global namespace alone, it will allow for the memory allocated to variables inside of the closure - the function we wrapped the code in - to be collected faster because they are out of scope once the closure's code is finished executing.

Note that with the `function change` declared in the closure, it will not be available to access in the global scope. If you wanted it available in the global scope it would not make as much sense to do it in this fashion.

*Allow for the function to have the change passed in to it by argument*

Inside of the `()` area for a function is where arguments can be passed in. In javascript, their type is dynamic. Using `function change(newMessage)` means that you can use the `newMessage` variable inside of the function. It is implicitly locally scoped. This will allow for all sorts of different messages, by passing in the new message `change('byebye');` like this:

```
(function(){
 var msg = 'hello';
 function change(newMessage){
  msg = newMessage;
 }
 change('byebye');
 alert(msg);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `change()` to call the function:

```
change();
```

This changes the value of the variable. Now you can alert the new value:

```
alert( msg ); // "byebye"
```